# How to remove sub-folders from Ubuntu One or only sync the parent folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, directory

I have been syncing several sub-folders of a single folder one by one so as to be able not to sync all sub-folders on all devices. Now I want to sync only the parent folder.

It seems to me that there is no way to do that automatically, right?

But, is there a way to remove all the sub-folders from the server, so I can add the parent folder?

Comment: Given your replies in comments to the answers below, perhaps it would be a good idea to re-word your question so that it matches more clearly what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I guess with Joseph's answer, everything is clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and was unsuccessful in solving it through the control panel, but I did solve it through the web interface. The control panel only controls how this device syncs with the cloud, so it can't remove folders from the cloud.

Both answers offered so far seem to misunderstand the question, so here is a clarification of what I believe was the original problem:

Let's say that inside `~/Parent/` you synchronize `~/Parent/child1/` and `~/Parent/child2/`, but not `~/Parent/child3/` or `~/Parent/child4/`. Now you want instead to synchronize `~/Parent/` along with anything I put in there. But when you try to synchronize `~/Parent/`, you get an error saying it overlaps with other things you've synchronized. You can stop synchronizing each of these folders through each device's Ubuntu One control panel, but the control panel cannot remove the folders from the cloud.

The solution is to forget the control panel and to log into https://one.ubuntu.com/files/, click on "More" to the right of each child folder, and select "X Stop synchronizing this folder." Ideally, you should now be able to synchronize the parent. But for me this never works unless I restart the sync daemon (from terminal: `killall ubuntuone-syncdaemon` then `ubuntuone-launch`). Then I can right click on the folder I want to sync and select "Ubuntu One > Synchronize this folder".

Maybe the developers will figure out in the future an easier way to synchronize the -parent folder that just includes all the already-synchronized child folders by default.

Comment: Do not use "killall ubuntuone-syncdaemon" but instead use `u1sdtool --quit` to stop the syncdaemon.

Comment: Thanks Joseph! I don't use U1 anymore, so I can't test your solution, but I'm sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to synchronize a folder and not its subfolders.

One thing you could do is synchronize a folder, move all the subfolders somewhere else, and use symlinks to make them appear to be inside the synchronized folder.

Since Ubuntu One ignores symlinks, the subfolders would not be synchronized.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I have probably asked it the wrong way. Sorry for that, and thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

roberto. you may be right with what you said (actually I don't know) but I do not believe you answered the question.

I beliebe it's like this:

You have in Ubuntu One /Mystorage/ and then there come the folders like

/Ubuntu One/

/whateverfolder1/

/whateverfolder2/

what Martin did is he moved his folders all into /Ubuntu One/ which he probably should not have been done. I am doing the same mistake right now because I do not see a solution right now to stop the file synchronisation without lots of confusion.

What Martin should have done is to right click any folder in his HOME directory in Linux and select Ubuntu One-Synchronize this folder

then he could also undo and redo and have his folders synched or not synched individually.

the /Ubuntu One/ folder is always in sync and also all its subfolders.

I just wrote to the ubuntu support team and asked them to move all my folders out of the Ubuntu One folder.

How do symlinks work, Roberto? How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer my question either. Now it is almost sure that I asked it the wrong way. Sorry again for that, and thanks for your help as well. PS: symbolic links work that way: ln -s TARGET LINK_NAME. Very easy :)